# No entiendo el uso de std::setw

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de un libro de C++ que utilizo para aprender el lenguaje, y no consigo comprender del todo el uso de **std::setw** y su uso conjunto con **std::left** (por defecto) y **std::right**. De hecho, no se como, he dado con la clave para realizar lo que queria hacer, pero no entiendo por que funciona..

Diganme si estoy equivocado, por favor, pero segun lo que yo pienso:

- El bucle for j hace que se despliegue el primer triangulo de *.
- La linea **cout << right << setw(16 - i);** hace que se vayan separando las b de los * en cada linea hacia la derecha de cada *, en 16 -i espacios, partiendo del caracter inmediato a cada *.
- El bucle for z añade el triangulo compuesto por letras b.
- La instruccion **cout << right << setw(4 + i * 2);** es donde ya me pierdo, porque no conseguia que saliese ese resultado que es el que yo quiero, y no me digais por que, si fue intuicion o que, pero me dio por ponerle el "* 2" y asi si que salio xD

Por favor, se que es mucho pedir, pero si alguien pudiese explicarme el por que funciona y por que me lio tanto con esa instruccion se lo agradeceria enormemente.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    #include <iomanip>

    using std::setw;
    using std::right;
    using std::left;

    int main() {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            for(int j = i; j >=1; j--)
                cout << '*';

            cout << right << setw(16 - i);

            for(int z = 11 - i; z >= 1; z--)
                cout  << 'b';

            cout << right << setw(4 + i * 2);

            for(int y = 11 - i; y >= 1; y--)
                cout << 'a';

            cout << endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Tambien pongo la salida que me da a mi, por si no fuese portable.

```
*              bbbbbbbbbb     aaaaaaaaaa
**             bbbbbbbbb       aaaaaaaaa
***            bbbbbbbb         aaaaaaaa
****           bbbbbbb           aaaaaaa
*****          bbbbbb             aaaaaa
******         bbbbb               aaaaa
*******        bbbb                 aaaa
********       bbb                   aaa
*********      bb                     aa
**********     b                       a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si entendí tu pregunta  `cout << right << setw(4 + i * 2);` forma la pirámide de espacios en medio por que el espacio que incrementas a `4` por la suma de `i` es duplicado, piensa que si tuvieras esta instrucción `cout << right << setw(4 + i);` tu resultado sería algo como:

```
*              bbbbbbbbbb    aaaaaaaaaa
**             bbbbbbbbb     aaaaaaaaa
***            bbbbbbbb      aaaaaaaa
****           bbbbbbb       aaaaaaa
*****          bbbbbb        aaaaaa
******         bbbbb         aaaaa
*******        bbbb          aaaa
********       bbb           aaa
*********      bb            aa
**********     b             a
```

Al multiplicar `i` por `2` el espacio que dejas para cada línea entre la `b` y la `a` es duplicado, cuando `i = 1` va a dejar 6 espacios, en la siguiente línea dejará `8`y así progresivamente.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes el bucle `i` que sirve para imprimir las filas. Para cada fila vas a imprimir un número de asteriscos igual a la posición de la fila (fila 1 -> 1 asterisco, fila 2 -> 2 asteriscos, ...).

El siguiente elemento a imprimir es la secuencia de `b`. Como pretendes que esta nueva secuencia empiece en siempre en la misma columna tienes que añadir después de la secuencia de asteriscos un número de espacios de tal forma que `número de asteriscos + número de espacios = x` o, dicho de otra forma, `número de espacios = x - número de asteriscos`, siendo en tu caso `x=16`. Como la secuencia de asteriscos es directamente proporcional a la fila, el número de asteriscos deberá ser inversamente proporcional. De aquí te sale el primer `setw`: `setw(16 - i);`:

```
Fila i = i asteriscos + (16 - i) espacios

Fila 01: 1 asterisco  + (16-1) espacios = 16
Fila 02: 2 asteriscos + (16-2) espacios = 16
Fila 03: 3 asteriscos + (16-3) espacios = 16
...
```

Bien, ahora se imprime la secuencia de `b` y la secuencia de `a` de tal forma que el hueco entre ellas forma una pirámide de espacios, ocupando la secuencia total 24 caracteres. Ambas secuencias, `a` y `b`, evolucionan de forma inversamente proporcional al número de fila. Así tenemos:

```
24 = longitud_secuencia_b + espacios + longitud_secuencia_a
24 = (10-i) + espacios + (10-i)
24 = 2 * (10-i) + espacios
```

Y ahora intentamos calcular el número de espacios a insertar en función del número de la fila:

```
espacios = 24 - 2*(10 - i)
espacios = 24 - 20 + 2*i
espacios = 4 + 2*i
```

Si comparas este último resultado con el segundo `setw` verás que la ecuación es exactamente la misma: `setw(4 + i * 2);`

¿Por qué ese `x2`? Porque el número de elementos en la secuencia `a` se reduce en uno en cada fila y lo mismo para la secuencia `b`, en consecuencia, el número de espacios tendrá que crecer en dos unidades entre una fila y la siguiente si pretendes que la secuencia total ocupe el mismo número de caracteres.